# MemoryError for ScikitLearn Kernel PCA

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a data set consisting of roughly 170,000 input vectors having 3,000 features each. On this data set I would like to perform a Kernel PCA using [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.KernelPCA.html#sklearn.decomposition.KernelPCA). Unfortunately, any attempt always results in:

> MemoryError

I'm on a PC having 32 GB of RAM and setting the *copy_X* parameter to 'false' doesn't help. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though SO seems to be a better fit for this question, there is a theoretical knowledge of the algorithm to keep in mind.

On [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_principal_component_analysis#Large_Datasets) there is a specific paragraph related to large samples. Just like (kernel) SVM, you need to compute the whole matrix $K(x_i, x_j)$. Where $x_i$'s are your sample points. You have 170 000 of them, so 170 000 ^ 2 terms to compute (and store) in the matrix $K$. Even with enough memory, I doubt the calculation would end.

An approach could be (from wikipedia) :

> One way to deal with this is to perform clustering on the dataset, and populate the kernel with the means of those clusters. Since even this method may yield a relatively large K, it is common to compute only the top P eigenvalues and eigenvectors of K.

Or to look for [streaming implementations](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v51/ghashami16.pdf) of KPCA.

Comment: Thank you very much for your helpful reply. However, I'm still looking for a way to direclty apply the theory. Are there any functions I could use in scikit-learn, Python in general (or any other framework) to automatically cluster the data first?

Comment: @Hagbard as far as I know, there is no such thing...